# implementing FB login to website; allow user to change password?

Tags: php, facebook, web

I've implemented FB connect on my website, and all works fine.

The procedure is pretty standard:

```
user clicks FB button on my website
I capture the user's FB  email, name
I create a new user in my database with the users email and name
```

On each user's profile page, I allow the user to change their password.  It occured to me that if a user logs in with FB (or Google for that matter), I should not allow them to change their password, since 1) I can't affect their FB password, and 2) they really have no password on my site.  Does this make sense or am I missing something?  Is it good enough to just grey out the password form on their profile or is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks -

Comment: That depends, if your website only accept FB or Google login exclusively, then you wouldn't need a password field at all in your user's profile because authentication is already taken care by FB. Else if you need your own user login besides FB, I would suggest you do it like the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this procedure.

```
User clicks on FB button on my website
I capture the user's FB email and name
I create a new user in my database with the users email, name and random password
Once user is logged in he can change the password
Now the user have two options how to log in on my website
 - using FB authorization
 - using email and password
  It's up to the user which one he use.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: great idea - thanks so much!  I'll implement mine the same way.

Comment: But what if the user changes his email? Isn't it better to user the facebook-ID then? :)

Comment: Maybe it is good idea to store FB-ID and check if the email changed or not after user log in.